# Issue during Angular validating form with two radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

Today I approached a weird case: I got form with two radio buttons. 
When one, currently checked, is disabled, form shouldn't be able to submit.
The thing is, that standard way with `form.$valid` doesn't work :-/

**UPDATE**
Even if I watch for changes in form, `$invalid` status is not reflected on `ng-disable` save button. Why?

```
<input name="someRadio" ng-disabled="true" type="radio" value="CURRENT" ng-model="RadioPen.data.radio" required>
<input name="someRadio" type="radio" value="DELAYED" ng-model="RadioPen.data.radio" required>

<button ng-disabled="!RadioPen.someForm.$valid">Save</button>
```

Here is full working example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/cachaito/pen/XpJyXw?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form.$valid` is working fine. The `required` check works based on the `value` of a form element. Since you are already providing a value to the model associated with the radio buttons, i.e, `RadioPen.data.radio`, in your controller script, the `required` condition is being fulfilled and hence the form is getting validated. Here is a modified and working version of your code where I have removed the initialization of the model for the radio buttons.

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('RadioPen', radioPen)

function radioPen($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data= {};
  $scope.RadioPen = vm;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test"> 
  <form name="RadioPen.someForm" ng-controller="RadioPen" novalidate>
    Current
    <input name="someRadio" ng-disabled="true" type="radio" value="CURRENT" ng-model="RadioPen.data.radio" required>
    Delayed
    <input name="someRadio" type="radio" value="DELAYED" ng-model="RadioPen.data.radio" required>

    <button ng-disabled="!RadioPen.someForm.$valid">Save</button>
    {{'is valid: ' + RadioPen.someForm.$valid}}
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Now behavior of `.$valid` seems legit. Now I must find best way to achieve my goal. Best regards!

Comment: @cachaito No problem. If my answer helped you, I'd appreciate if you approve it. :)

Comment: You got my voice :)

Comment: I've updated my gist with new code for checking form `$invalid` status. Unfortunately something doesn't work as expected :-/

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
<div ng-app="test"> 
  <form name="ctrl.someForm" ng-controller="RadioPen as ctrl" novalidate>
    Current
    <input name="someRadio" ng-disabled="true" type="radio" value="CURRENT" ng-model="RadioPen.data.radio" required>
    Delayed
    <input name="someRadio" type="radio" value="DELAYED" ng-model="RadioPen.data.radio" required>

    <button ng-disabled="ctrl.someForm.$invalid">Save</button>
    {{'is invalid: ' + ctrl.someForm.$invalid}}
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Except `controller as` and using `$invalid` instead `!$valid` what is different? Btw. it doesn't work: codepen.io/cachaito/pen/PWwXmV?editors=1011 :-)